# how to double a number in assembly in one command?

Tags: assembly

I have a question
I got this assembly code and I want to double all this 3 numbers in one command.

```
  x: DW 1
  y: DB 2
  z: DB 3
```

I know the answer for this question is:

```
  SHL DWORD[x], 1
```

But I don't understand why? I mean how does it work?

Thank you

Comment: Just as adding a zero to 13 makes it ten times bigger (130). Just in binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x: DW 1
y: DB 2
z: DB 3
```

When viewed as a DWORD in binary the above variables would equal:

```
00000011000000100000000000000001
```

x86 systems are little-endian, hence `x` which is located first in memory is shown in the least significant part of the DWORD, and `z` in the most significant part.

If we shift these bits one bit to the left (which is what the `SHL` instruction does), we get:

```
00000110000001000000000000000010
```

Let's insert some spaces to group the bits into one word and two bytes:

```
00000110 00000100 0000000000000010

   z=6      y=4        x=2
```